# I have two different types of condition in my model to check lr_no number how can I check in if else condition in controller

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ajax, codeigniter

In my model I have two different types of condition for check `lr_no` how can I  check condition in control  I am trying like this.

View:

```
$('#lr_no').change(function(event) {
    var lr_no = $('#lr_no').val();
    $.ajax({
    url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>crossing/crossing_cash_memo/CashMemoController/fetchCrossType",
    type:"POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
                lr_no :lr_no
      },
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        },
    error:function(data){
        alert("error message"+data);
    },async:false,

 });
});
```

controller:

```
public function fetchCrossType(){
    $id        = $this->input->post('lr_no');            
}
```

Model:

```
 public function getBiltyNo($lr_no){ 

        $crossQuery = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('truck_freight')
                      ->join('crossing_received', 'crossing_received.crossing_rec_frtno = truck_freight.fr_memo_ids')
                      ->where('crossing_rec_type','cross_received')
                      ->get()->result();

        if ($crossQuery != "") {
            $query = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('truck_freight')
                        ->join('crossing_received', 'crossing_received.crossing_rec_frtno = truck_freight.fr_memo_ids')
                        ->join('frieght_challan', 'frieght_challan.frieght_id = truck_freight.fr_memo_ids')
                        ->join('challan_bilties', 'challan_bilties.challan_id = frieght_challan.dispatch_id')
                        ->join('bilty', 'bilty.id = challan_bilties.bilty_id')
                        ->join('delivery_stock',"bilty.id = delivery_stock.sbilty_id")
                        ->where('sstatus','delivery_bilty')
                        ->where('lr_no', $lr_no)

                        ->get()->num_rows();
            if ($query >0) {
                return array('form_message' => 'LR no Found', 'form_status' => 'bilty_found');

            } else {
                return array('form_message' => 'LR NO not found (in Crossing Received)', 'form_status' => 'biltynotfound');
            }

            } else {
            return array('form_message' => 'crossing not received', 'form_status' => 'notRecevied');
           }


      }

       public function getBiltyByNo($bilty_no){
        $crossQuery = $this->db->select('*')
                       ->from('delivery_local_truck_freight')
                       ->join('crossing_received', 'crossing_received.crossing_rec_frtno = delivery_local_truck_freight.loc_truck_ids')
                       ->where('crossing_rec_type', 'del_loc_cross_received')
                       ->get()->num_rows();



        if ($crossQuery > 0) {
            $query = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('delivery_local_truck_freight')
                        ->join('crossing_received', 'crossing_received.crossing_rec_frtno = delivery_local_truck_freight.loc_truck_ids')
                        ->join('delivery_local_freight_challan', 'delivery_local_freight_challan.loc_frieght_id = delivery_local_truck_freight.loc_truck_ids')
                        ->join('delivery_local_challan_bilties', 'delivery_local_challan_bilties.challan_id = delivery_local_freight_challan.local_id')
                        ->join('bilty', 'bilty.id = delivery_local_challan_bilties.bilty_id')
                        ->join('delivery_stock',"bilty.id = delivery_stock.sbilty_id")
                        ->where('sstatus','delivery_local_received')
                        ->where('crossing_received.crossing_rec_type','del_loc_cross_received')
                        ->where('lr_no', $bilty_no)
                        ->get()->num_rows();
            if ($query == 1) {
                return array('form_message' => 'LR NO Found', 'form_status' => 'bilty_found');

            } else {
                return array('form_message' => 'LR No not found (in Delivery Crossing Received)', 'form_status' => 'biltynotfound');
            }

        } else {
            return array('form_message' => 'crossing not received', 'form_status' => 'notRecevied');
        }

    }
```

How can I check condition in controller for two different model conditions

Comment: Please explain in depth what the condition wants to check-in Controller.

Comment: @sanjaysisodiya I want check my `lr_no` in both model functions `getBiltyNo` and `getBiltyByNo` I do not know how to call both function of my model from controller

Comment: if you added your model in config > autoload, then in controller just do  `$this->whatever_name_model->getBiltyNo($parameters_here)`